# R: Unused argument error in round

Tags: r

I have a data.frame mdf that looks like this;

```
       date     time moon Sunrise Sunset            time.tmp
1    1.9.12  0:00:00 0.00    6:52  20:26 2013-06-12 00:00:00
2    1.9.12  1:00:00 0.00    6:52  20:26 2013-06-12 01:00:00
3    1.9.12  2:00:00 0.00    6:52  20:26 2013-06-12 02:00:00
4    1.9.12  3:00:00 0.00    6:52  20:26 2013-06-12 03:00:00
5    1.9.12  4:00:00 0.00    6:52  20:26 2013-06-12 04:00:00
```

when I try to use round() on the Sunrise and Sunset columns I get an error 'unused argument'. 
I can't see why.

This is the line of code I'm using;

```
round(strptime(mdf$Sunrise, format="%H:%M"), units = "hours")
```

and this is the error:

```
Error in round.POSIXt(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  unused argument (units = "hours")
```

If I use this

```
round(strptime("6:52", format="%H:%M"), units="hours")
```

I get this error in return

```
Error in round.POSIXt(list(sec = 0, min = 52L, hour = 6L, mday = 12L,  : 
  unused argument (units = "hours")
```

SessionInfo() returns

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

Any suggestions as to how to solve this error?

This line of code is part of what was suggested in another question asked here; [Place 1 heatmap on another with transparency in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043864/place-1-heatmap-on-another-with-transparency-in-r)

Comment: `round(strptime("6:52", format="%H:%M"), units="hours")` works for me.  Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich you're example throws me an error. Edited the question to include this.

Comment: Joshua's example works for me as well. Please include in your `sessionInfo` the packages you've got loaded.

Comment: Joshua's example works fine for me. Maybe you redefined `round` somewhere? Try it in a fresh session.

Comment: Then something is masking `round.POSIXt` in your session. You were probably warned about this when you loaded a package, or you defined another `round.POSIXt` function yourself.

Comment: you can also explicitly ask for the right function by doing `base::round.POSIXt(strptime("6:52", format="%H:%M"), units="hours")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments suggesting that round.POSIXt was masked or redefined in the session we're very helpful. I started a fresh session and the code is working now.

Comment: thanks for letting us know, but voting to close the question as too localized ...